# Laravel Change Schema Dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I am working on a project in laravel 5.8 and postgres. I have one main database, a global schema with master data and other schemas for each organization. The schema with the master data is the default connection.
I am attempting to search for a specific phone number in each schema and return all the schema names that a phone number appears in.
My first attempt was this, but the schema does not switch from the default schema and the search does not occur.

My code looks like this :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        $phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');

        $facilities = Facility::all();

        foreach($facilities as $facility) {

            $params = $facility['schema_name'];

            $connection = DatabaseConnection::setConnection($params);

            $fac = Patient::where(function ($query) use ($phone_number) {
                $query->where('phone_number', '=', $phone_number);
            });

            $facility = $fac;

        }       

        return response()->json(compact('token', 'connection', 'facility'));
    }
```

I have a helper function, that looks like this :

```
public static function setConnection($params)
    {
        config(['database.connections.onthefly' => [
        
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => $params,
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ]]);

        return DB::connection('onthefly');
    }
```

I have also tried to switch schemas using `DB::statement("SET search_path TO $params");` before trying the helper function which did not work.

Any advice/references on how to switch the schema dynamically will be appreciated.

Comment: hi would love to know if you ever find the answer for this. I need to perform similar things basically

Comment: same here. `Schema::connection('mysql_external')` not working

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while on this only to discover the obvious solution; dynamically change the table name to include the schema prefix and set the connection's database name to an empty string (not null).

Note this might cause issues with database migrations, but I dont use those. A potential solution would be to have two connections; one with the database set for migrations and the other for SQL operations.

Additional info...

The MySQL connector use a PDO to connect to the database. The database name is not required; so in database config set it to an empty string.

```
'database' => '',
```

I created a base model to intercept the call to `getTable()`.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Model extends BaseModel
{
    protected ?string $schema = null;

    public function getSchema(): ?string
    {
        return $this->schema;
    }

    public function getTable()
    {
        $t = parent::getTable();
        $s = $this->getSchema();

        if ($s) {
            return $s.'.'.$t;
        } else {
            return $t;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your model classes (that extends from your base model), set the schema:

```
class Product extends BaseModel
{
    protected ?string $schema = 'store-123';
}
```

This will produce a query like:

```
select * from `store-123`.`products`
```

To make it dynamic you can override `getSchema()` in your model and put the logic in there to figure out what schema to use:

```
public function getSchema(): ?string
{
    // figure out what schema here
}
```